# Creating a layout for email using html and css - word wrap

Tags: html, css, email, layout, word-wrap

Work with html layout for email is a real nightmare!

Well, my layout is almost finished, I spent 2 days working on it. The only problem I could not solve yet is related with word wrap. Here is a part of it:

[image]

But sometimes the content of the table cell (div) is a url (link) like this:

> https://login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=12&ct=1458752139&rver=6.4.6456.0&wp=MBI_SSL_SHARED&wreply=https:%2F%2Fmail.live.com%2Fdefault.aspx&lc=1146&id=67855&mkt=pt-br&cbcxt=mai&bk=1458152139&uaid=65b544e4d6a0424fa4b0dce1d5abaceb&pid=0

And here is the result:

[image]

My goal is to make this kind of url to be "word-wrap" inside the cell without expanding it. I already tried many ways to solve this, without sucess. Here is what I got so far:

```
<div style="width: 100%; word-wrap: break-word; overflow: auto; display: inline-block;">
```

Here is the complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/uayazs59/1/

Please, can someone help me? Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the width of your `link's` `DIV` is making the whole table act improperly so change your width to a spicific amount like: `width: 570px;`

```
<div style="width: 570px; word-wrap: break-word; overflow: auto; display: inline-block;">
```

Comment: Hi Graphicoding! Thank you! You are right, when using a fixed width size, it works... I already tried this before, and did not work, but I think I was not using inline-block :( About stylesheets, you mean between <head> tags? Do you think it can work with email layouts? I am making tests with Outlook, Gmail and Yahoo (mainly). Do you think they accept stylesheets? Thanks again!

Comment: Oh right, I forgot that this was an email. I don't believe stylesheets are accepted by most. And glad I could help out.

Comment: @Paruba for email, the more you "design" the more you have to choose... support Outlook, or support Gmail/Yahoo. Outlook has many restrictions that won't work for Gmail/Yahoo. And Gmail/Yahoo allows many more things than Outlook does. It is nearly impossible to target "all" email clients effectively if you want some intricate design. Keep things as simple as possible and you should be okay though. Inline styles work fine in most clients... but stick to CSS2 specifications and avoid CSS3 if you need to support Outlook.

Comment: @Scott, thank you for the tips... I am back to 1999 doing this layout, using tables to put image and texts in the right place... After many hours and tests, it is working in Outlook, MS Outlook, Gmail, Yahoo and others!